# Show json data into tableview

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I parsing json using NSJSONSerialization class and able to show all data in console log. But not getting any idea how to display all data into table view. Below is my code. Please help me how to show country name and flag image into tableview. Thanks in Advance.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{
    /*  NSLog(@"%d",webdata.length);

     NSString *receivedstring=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:webdata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"%@",receivedstring);
     */ 
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: webdata options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    feedforentry=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"worldpopulation"];

    // NSLog(@"%d",feedforentry.count);


    for (NSDictionary *review in feedforentry) {

        name = [review objectForKey:@"country"];
        NSLog(@"%@",name);
        NSString *populations = [review objectForKey:@"population"];
        NSLog(@"%@",populations);
        NSString *rank = [review objectForKey:@"rank"];
        NSLog(@"%@",rank);
        NSString *flag = [review objectForKey:@"flag"];
        NSLog(@"%@",flag);



    }

    [self.tableview reloadData];


}




-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [feedforentry count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    }



    //cell.textLabel.text=[[feedforentry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]nam ];
    return cell;
}





- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

I want to show country name and flag image into tableview. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
  if(!cell)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

  }

    NsDictionary *review =  [feedforentry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *rank = [review objectForKey:@"rank"];
    Cell.textlabel.text = rank;
    Return cell;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is the right idea. In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you just need to get the details

```
NSDictionary *countryInfo = feedforentry[indexPath.row];
NSString *name = countryInfo[@"country"];
NSString *flag = countryInfo[@"flag"];
```

Then use those values to setup the cell.

Answer (score 0):

The method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is where you should configure your cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = feedforentry[indexpath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", dict[@"flag"], dict[@"country@"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You want `dict[@"flag"]`, not `dict[flag]`. Same for `country`.

Comment: Thanks, hate coding outside xCode.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSSting *CellIdntifier=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdntifier];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdntifier];
}

NSDictionary *dict = feedforentry[indexpath.row];

cell.textLabel.text= dict[@"country"];
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dict[@"flag"]]]];

return cell;
}
```